# How to access post data in couchDb?

Tags: couchdb

CouchDb has a [req](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.3.x/json-structure.html#request-object) object that is available to update functions.How can I access the data that I have posted to that update function from the req object?

Comment: As it is written, either use `body` or `form`, depending on the format you sent the data as.

Comment: Well I posted the data from my application.So is it body then?Cause I got undefined with that.

Comment: You can always use `body`. But if you sent the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, then you can use `form` as well. *edit:* If you get undefined, are you sure it is a POST request?

Comment: Okay.Thanks.I will try once again then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a lot of time on trying to get the posted data through req.body() I finally decided to just post the data in a query string.All of it was then available in the query object.This [link](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/06/08/exploring-the-request-in-a-couchdb-show-function/) was helpful in debugging what req object actually contained.

The [couchDb wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers#Usage) also offers a simillar suggestion.